# Is it possible to combine OutOfMemoryHandler and MapStore in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I know it is possible to store every entry on a Map at Hazelcast to backing DataStore via implementation of MapStore interface but in our application we don't want that, we only want that if our application is running on danger of getting OutOfMemory Exception, it evicts certain percentage of data in the memory (with LRU principle) but during the eviction it store evicted entries to data store and load them again if entry key asked again.

I know that the OutOfMemoryHandler interface exist to manage OutOfMemory situations, %25 Eviction policy exists and MapStore also.

What I don't know can I combine them all?

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `IMap.putTransient()` to put your entries in IMap but not trigger MapStore.store()
- `IMap.evict()` (or auto eviction) will not trigger MapStore removal, i.e. it will just remove from the IMap.

However I don't suggest this approach because once the jvm gets `OutOfMemoryError` it can become unstable so applying such business logic would not be possible. Also `OutOfMemoryHandler` may not be called even if JVM throws `OutOfMemoryError` because the error may be thrown from an external (user) thread and Hazelcast may not be informed about it.

Comment: Ok, it seems, it is not clever to use OutOfMemoryHandler but  can I then configure %25 Eviction policy and with an EntryEvictedListener persist evicted entries via MapStore and load those in the case they are queried again. The reason I ask, let say we will have 1000000 entries in Hazelcast we don't want to persist all of those via MapStore (our data is already stored some other place), we will fill Hazelcast but we don't want to write code reload evicted entries again from our store, instead if they are evicted Hazelcast to store those and reload if it is requested again(so only the 200K).

Comment: you can only implement maploader methods to have read through, and not implement and mapstore methods so entries you put into hazelcast is not persisted to DB. And use your custom mechanism to persist evicted entries back to DB.